# Attach Javadoc to Library in NetBeans

Tags: javadoc, netbeans6.1

I'm new to using the NetBeans IDE. When I try to look at the documentation for say the java API (example, `System` class), it says that the javadoc is not installed. How do I install the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Right click the project
2. Select Properties
3. Select "Java Sources
4. Classpath" Click "Manage Java
   Platforms..."
5. Click the platform being used by the
   project
6. Click the Javadoc tab
7. Click the "Add ZIP/Folder..." button
8. Select the Javadoc you have
   downloaded to your machine

Comment: Where can I download the javadoc?

Comment: Again does not answer the question of how to attach javadoc for a library.

Answer (score 5):

First you download the javadoc.

Second go to Tools-->Java Platforms and select Javadoc tab from the Java Platform Manager. Click the Add ZIP/Folder.

Comment: Works perfect, on Leopard I added the "/Library/Java/Home/doc/api" folder and now I can access the javadoc from the pulldown menu from a selected class or package name.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, which is how to attach javadoc for a library (not the JDK).

Answer (score 3):

For netbeans 7.0

1. Download javadoc
2. Right click project
3. Properties
4. Libraries
5. Manage platforms
6. Add Zip/Folder

If you wish to add a specific libray api documentation (Say for example JavaFX)

1. Libraries
2. Compile Tab - Edit
3. Browse and give the javadoc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you can reference it at: http://java.sun.com/javase/reference/api.jsp until someone is able to answer your real question!

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans right click on your project, then:

- Properties
- Libraries

then select the library you added and select edit, there is a window for you to add your javadocs there. You have to add the .jar file first, or I am told you can add the entire folder and it will add the javadocs for you. I have never had any luck with that method tho.

Comment: Most libraries are not really libraries, they are just jars.